# Instantiation of declared (but undefined) template ['X' has already been instantiated]

Tags: c++, c++20

I ran into this issue when trying to postpone the definition of a function template. The solution was straightforward, but I am still curious as to why there was an issue in the first place.

```
// Declaration
template <class T> int foo ();

void bar () { foo<void> (); } // NOK
// template <class T> void bar () { auto f = foo <void> (); } // NOK
// template <class T> void foobar () { foo <void> (); } // OK

// Specialisation
template <> int foo<void> () { return 0; } // int foo<void>(void)' has already been instantiated
```

How the compiler can instantiate a template without its definition goes beyond me, but I figure the error code is probably correct.

What makes the first two usages of foo() fail compilation but the third usage pass compilation?

**Edit I**

As per request, I uncommented one of the two erroneous passages and updated the title.

**Edit II**

As it turns out, the [following](https://godbolt.org/z/TMj1f36ax) compiles fine online but not on my home machines.

```
template <class T> int foo ();
template <class T> void bar () { auto f = foo <void> (); } // NOK
template <class T> void foobar () { foo <void> (); } // OK
template <> int foo<void> () { return 0; }
```

However, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/18YW7c1sM) fails online...

```
template <class T> int foo ();
void bar () { foo<void> (); } // NOK
template <> int foo<void> () { return 0; }
```

...but [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Wz144ve53) does not (specialisation removed).

```
template <class T> int foo ();
void bar () { foo<void> (); } // NOK
```

I still do not understand why `foo<void>()` is considered instantiated by the compiler when it is clearly undefined. But I accept the given answer since it helped shed some light on the issue at hand.

Comment: please include the code that has the error (ie not in comments) and the compiler error message in the question

Comment: FWIW, function template specialization is kind of being phased out, or at least minimized.  It's rules are somewhat complex and they don't interact with the overload system at all.  That is a couple reasons why that customization point was removed from C++20.  Try to use overloads if at all possible.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "being phased out"? Do you mean concepts and constraints?

Comment: @AndyG That goes back to that we can no longer specialize function templates in `std::` starting in C++20.  At least for me that removes most of the function template specializations that I have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you actually instantiate a template it is just a ... template. There is no reason for the compiler to issue an error for this code:

```
template <class T> int foo ();

template <class T> void bar () { auto f = foo <void> (); }
```

Only when you try to instantiate `bar` and call it, the linker will complain about a missing definition. Without providing a definition for `foo<void>` this will fail to link:

```
int main() { bar<int>(); }
```

You can add a definition for `foo<void>` after `bar` to make the code ok:

```
template <class T> int foo ();    
template <class T> void bar () { auto f = foo <void> (); }   
template <> int foo<void>() { return 1;}

int main() {
     bar<int>();
}
```

Same for `3` because `foobar` is a template that you do not instantiate. Only when you instantiate the template you get an actual function. On the other hand, this:

```
template <class T> int foo ();
void bar () { foo<void> (); } 

int main() { }
```

again fails to link (`source>:3: undefined reference to int foo<void>()`) because `bar` is not a template.

Comment: Well, yes. This is how I would have imagined it to work. However, it does not. Adding a specialisation after bar() always triggers said compiler error (tested in clean MSVC2019 project with c++14, c++17, and c++latest).

Comment: @ProbabilisticS I already asked you to provide a [mcve] and the compiler error, without that I can only guess what is the problem in code you did not show. Details do matter. When I have to remove some `//` then thats already a source of uncertainty, because I dont know if then I am looking at the same code as you do

Comment: @ProbabilisticS the code that is now in the question is the last paragraph in the answer. You can open a new question when you have a follow-up question on slightly different code

Comment: @ProbabilisticS don't get me wrong, I am curious to see your code and then try to help you. Its just too common to have questions without the error and/or incomplete code and in the worst case thats a waste of effort for both the asker and the one trying to answer. I think my ansewr does adress your question in its current state, hence different code should go to a new question

Comment: I will try to make my next question copy-pastable (and I do see the issues that arise from having to modify the code, so I am sorry about that). But as far as I understand, the current code snippet (identical to what I currently try to run) should compile just fine from a language point of view (based on your answer and what I see on https://godbolt.org/). No idea why it fails to do so on either of my machines.

Comment: If I accept this answer, should I also edit the initial post to state in what way it answered the question?

Comment: @ProbabilisticS fwiw, on gobolt there is a `share` dropdown on the upper right corner where you can get a permanent link to your code.

Comment: @ProbabilisticS actually yes. Your edit invalidated my answer because my answer refers to `3` which isnt present anymore. Editing questions after you received answer is always a little problematic. Though, also my fault, I shouldn't have answered **before** the question was clarified. I can try to fix my answer when I find time for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a rule that you cannot give an explicit specialization after the compiler has already instantiated that specialization.  So,

`template <class T> int foo ();`  declares the template `foo`.
`template <class T> void bar () { auto f = foo <void> (); } // NOK`  Since the use of `foo<void>` in the body does not involve `T` it is resolved immediately.  The compiler tries to instantiate `foo<void>`.  It doesn't generate the body because it's not given in the above declaration, but that's not important for this step.
`template <class T> void foobar () { foo <void> (); } // OK`  same thing.  It uses the specialization `foo<void>`, which it still can't actually create the body for.
`template <> int foo<void> () { return 0; }`  Now you're in trouble!  You **cannot** define an explicit specialization for `foo<void>` because the compiler already used `foo<void>`.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization#In_detail)

> Specialization must be declared before the first use that would cause implicit instantiation, in every translation unit where such use occurs:

Comment: Thanks! So none of the examples with a trailing explicit specialisation should compile? Or is the cause of an implicit instantiation implementation-specific?

Comment: The "point of instantiation" is precisely defined in the standard.  My guess is that the compiler that didn't error has to do with it not being defined at the point of instantiation, and the compiler names the explicit specialization the same as the implicit that it couldn't make, so it linked.  I'm pretty sure that's not correct (Microsoft?)

Comment: Actually, the online compilers I tried (gcc, msvc, clang) accepted two out of the three usages of foo<void>(), so no difference there. My local copies of msvc only accept one.

Comment: But I think the compilers are free to do as they please here. From [c++draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec) 13.9.4.7: _If a template... is explicitly specialized, a declaration of that specialization shall be reachable from every use... that would cause an implicit instantiation...; no diagnostic is required._

Comment: And since I did not provide a declaration of the specialisation **before** its use, my example is ill-formed. Is that a reasonable interpretation?